# Symfony call on esp8266

Tags: symfony, request, hosting, esp8266

I have developed a Symfony project and need to communicate with my esp8266 via HTTP requests. Everything works perfectly locally, but once my site is hosted on Hostinger, I consistently get a timeout error. I reached out for assistance, but they were unsure of what could be causing the issue.
I am on the same wifi network, and there is no problem when running the project locally on WAMP. It also works with Postman.
I also tried using GuzzleHttp\Client, but without success.

Code symfony :

```
    #[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
    #[Route('/activateBottle/{id}', name: 'app_activateBottle')]
    public function activateBottle(WineGame $wineGame)
    {
        $client = HttpClient::create();
        try {
            $response = $client->request('GET', "https://" . $wineGame->getIpBottle() . "/activeBottle", [
                'timeout' => 30.0
            ]);
            if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
                $this->addFlash(
                    'success',
                    "La bouteille sonne"
                );
            } else {
                $this->addFlash(
                    'error',
                    "Erreur lors de la connexion à la bouteille"
                );
            }
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            $this->addFlash(
                'error',
                "Erreur lors de la connexion à la bouteille :" . $e
            );
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_wineGame', ['id' => $wineGame->getId()]);
    }
```

code esp8266 :

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

//co internet
const char * SSID = "XXXX";
const char * PASSWORD = "XXXX";

// obj webserver
ESP8266WebServer serverWeb(80);

//fonction server web
void activeBottle(){
  serverWeb.send(200, "text/html", "activeBottle");
  Serial.println("Je m'active");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");

  // mode de co wifi
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // démarer la co
  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connection...");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("\n");

  //mise en place server web
  serverWeb.on("/activeBottle", activeBottle);
  serverWeb.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(WiFi.isConnected()){
    serverWeb.handleClient();
  }
  else {
    
  }
}
```

error :
Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\TimeoutException: Idle timeout reached for "http://192.168.1.43/activeBottle". in /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/http-client/Chunk/ErrorChunk.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/http-client/Response/CommonResponseTrait.php(141): Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Chunk\ErrorChunk->isFirst() #1 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/http-client/Response/TransportResponseTrait.php(52): Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Response\CurlResponse::initialize() #2 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/src/Controller/UserController.php(141): Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Response\CurlResponse->getStatusCode() #3 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(163): App\Controller\UserController->activateBottle() #4 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(74): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() #5 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(184): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() #6 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php(35): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() #7 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(29): Symfony\Component\Runtime\Runner\Symfony\HttpKernelRunner->run() #8 /home/u196164738/domains/capucinemad.com/public_html/la-forge-des-enigmes/public/index.php(5): require_once('/home/u19616473...') #9 {main}

Comment: `http://192.168.1.43/activeBottle` that's a local address. You will have to point it to your home ip address and setup some sort of port forwarding on your router to your device (192.168....). That's why it works locally..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the network firewall (my school's WiFi), and I only need it to work if the request is made from the same WiFi. There's no need for anyone to access it from anywhere. Only people on the same WiFi should have access to it if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Then why are you hosting this code on an external server at Hostinger?

Comment: The website must be accessible on the internet. On one of the pages of the website, there is a button that calls this route. If we are on the right WiFi, it should make a call to the ESP8266, and if not, it should send an error message.

Comment: If you don't have access to any routers then this is never going to connect as is. You will have to make your esp "poll" a route on your server instead.

Comment: I am able to perform a GET request from my ESP to my server.
Should I make continuous GET requests? (I know how to perform a GET request to my server. But it doesn't seem optimal to make a GET request every X seconds to check a variable.)
Or should I establish a communication tunnel between the server and my ESP? (I have no idea if it's possible or how to set it up)

Comment: @CapucineMadoulaud, yes that's what [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) is, it is used in many applications. In your case this is probably the easiest to do and check every 5 or 10 seconds for changes. Creating a socket (or tunnel) you will still need to setup port forwarding etc.., and would add more complexity to your project.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for all these tips. I'll go with recurring calls, it will work well for my use (end-of-studies project). Have a great evening and thanks again.